# Is there a way to display drop down in Multi auto complete textview without typing even a single text

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

There a method to set threshold to 1. so that whenever user types a single character, match will be found and it displays drop down.

But what I really want here is, all items should be listed when I tap the **"multiautocompletetextview"**.  (just like a spinner.)

I cannot set threshold to zero or less than zero, if I set so that will be changed to 1.

Comment: hint: MultiAutoCompleteTextView is a **TextView**

Comment: @pskink I cannot understand ur answer.

Comment: @pskink of course its base class is a Textview. from this how can I get solution for this ?

Comment: ah i misunderstood dropdown with text area, sorry for that

Comment: @pskink its all right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `showDropDown()` in your `onCreate()`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#showDropDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#showDropDown%28%29)

> Displays the drop down on screen.